# existsSync не находит файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fs

Почему `fs.existsSync(localConfigPath)` не может увидеть файл, а `require(localConfigPath)` видит?

src/common/Config/Config.ts:

```
import IConfig from './IConfig';
import * as fs from 'fs';


let Configurator: IConfig;

const baseConfigPath: string = '../../../data/config.json';
const localConfigPath: string = '../../../data/config.local.json';

console.log('is exist: ' , fs.existsSync(localConfigPath), require(localConfigPath));
if (fs.existsSync(localConfigPath)) {
    Configurator = require(localConfigPath);
} else {
    Configurator = require(baseConfigPath);
}

export default Object.freeze(Configurator);
```

src/index.ts:

```
import Config from './common/Config/Config';

const app: express.Application = express();
console.log(Config);
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "fast_buld": "tsc && node public/index.js",
        "start": "node public/index.js",
        "build": "tsc",
        "tslint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "ip": "^1.1.5",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.15",
        "mysql2": "^2.1.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
        "@types/node": "^14.0.1",
        "tslint": "^6.1.2",
        "typescript": "^3.9.2"
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es5"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "strict": true,
        "outDir": "public",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

структура проекта:

```
 |
 |-- data
 |   |-- config.json
 |   |-- config.local.json
 |-- src
 |   |-- common
 |   |   |-- Config
 |   |   |   |--Config.ts
 |   |--index.ts
 |-- public
 |   |-- common
 |   |   |-- Config
 |   |   |   |--Config.js
 |   |--index.js
 |--package.json
 |--tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://ru.nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths) *Node.js*:

> Относительные пути будут разрезолвлены относительно текущей рабочией директории, определенной `process.cwd()`.

Поскольку процесс вы запускаете из рутовой директории, то путь будет разрешен относительно нее, а не папки с конфигом в `./src/common/Config`.

Для того, чтобы разрешить путь относительно директории файла `Config.ts`, воспользуйтесь модулем `path`.

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// ...

if (fs.existsSync(path.resolve(__dirname, localConfigPath))) {
    Configurator = require(localConfigPath);
} else {
    Configurator = require(baseConfigPath);
}
```